# Theme for elementary OS which makes active apps in the Dock easier to spot

Tags: release-hera, themes

I know there's a lot of people who think that active apps are really hard to notice in the Dock. Even with the dark theme installed that blue circle beneath the app is really tough to spot.

So can someone suggest a good, possibly dark, theme that makes active apps easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly this problem. :-)

1. Dock, right click: Settings.
2. Set the Theme to "Matte".

Now you can see the blue indicator.

[image: Settings]

[image: Dock]

Comment: You mean CTRL + right click, tried it too, but not getting any better :(
I've heard that they will improve this in EOS 6 though

Comment: Yes, or you just aim more precisely. ;-)
For me, the matte theme works pretty well. As you can see from the screenshot.